# OSMdroid - error: no suitable constructor found for Overlay(no arguments) constructor Overlay.Overlay(Context) is not applicable

Tags: android, overlay, osmdroid

While extending OSMdroid `Overlay` class in an application

```
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Overlay;
...
public class MapOverlayArea extends Overlay implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener, OnTouchListener  {

...
```

I receive an error:

> error: no suitable constructor found for Overlay(no arguments)
>   constructor Overlay.Overlay(Context) is not applicable

Comment: what version of osmdroid are you based off of?

Comment: did you provide the constructor it's looking for?

Comment: as highlighted by spy: provide the source code of your constructor. It should start with: super(context);

Comment: @spy :  osmdroid 4.3.  NO, i do not know HOW to provide said constructor.

Comment: @MKer will include and test.  get back 2 u asap

Comment: Your code would have the same error regardless of the IDE. I've removed references to Android Studio

Comment: @tonygil Please consider answering your own question and approve it instead of doing an edit to the question, this helps filter unanswered question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As indicated by the error message, the required constructor was missing.

```
public class MapOverlayArea extends Overlay implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener, OnTouchListener  {

    public MapOverlayArea(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
    }

    //....
}
```

Including the constructor as above, and calling it correctly from main activity using

```
MapOverlayArea mapOverlayArea = new MapOverlayArea(context);
```

solves the problem.

Comment: This post was discussed on meta http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323404/what-to-do-when-asker-offers-free-rep-points